# How to simulate ```WHERE``` from SQL or ```grep``` in Python to iterate and change data with certain attributes?

Tags: python, loops, iterator, iteration

I'm looking for a quick and simple tool to simulate `WHERE` from SQL. In a collection (list, set, dictionary, etc) of objects (each of which should be a list or class instance), I'd like to pick out just those with some certain properties/attributes and process them.

Example 1:

```
stuff = {
    "item1":[1,2,3],
    "item2":[4,5,6,7,8,9],
    "item3":[2,4,5]
}

def myfunc(this): # this is the dict above
    result = list()
    for item in this:
        if len(item) == 3:
            result.append(item)
    return result
```

In example 1, `myfunc` simulates `return items in stuff WHERE len(item)==3` which looks for and returns objects with length 3 in the dictionary `stuff`.

Example 2:

```
class thing:
    def init(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

item1 = thing(1,2,3)
item2 = thing(2,3,4)
item3 = thing(3,5,7)
test_list = [item1, item2, item3]

def func(this): # this is the test_list
    result = list()
    for item in this:
        if item.a % 2:
            result.append(item)
    return result
```

In example 2, `func` simulates `return items in test_list WHERE (item.a % 2) == 1` which returns objects where object.a is odd.

In both examples, a collection of objects is scanned for certain attributes that meet certain conditions and return those objects to be processed.

Comment: So `particle` class may have more variables of type not an int and you want to iterate through all variables of the class and only update the ones with type `int`?

Comment: I'm not sure how this is related to "sets"

Comment: I'd like to be able to just set out some conditions and iterate through every variable which meets those conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You could check in your loop if item is int, like

```
isinstance(item, int)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use __dict__ of an instance to access all the instance variables.
If you need to apply certain conditions like being int or something else you can use instainceof or similar.

```
class particle(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.height = 100

particles = [particle() for _ in range(2)]

for item in particles:
    item.height -= 1

for item in particles:
    for key in item.__dict__.keys():
        item.__dict__[key] = 5
```

item.__dict__[key] = 5 => Here I access the instance variables and change the value. If you need to add condition you can add here.

Answer (score 0):

#### Hacky code ahead (better solution below)

You can implement `__iter__` in a away that it will return all the attributes of the instance, then you will be able to pretty much achieve what you are looking for:

```
class particle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 90
        self.y = 70

    def __iter__(self):
        yield from self.__dict__


particles = [particle() for _ in range(2)]

for particle in particles:
    for attribute in particle:
        current_val = getattr(particle, attribute)
        if isinstance(current_val, int):
            setattr(particle, attribute, current_val - 1)

for particle in particles:
    print(particle.x, particle.y)
```

Outputs

```
89 69
89 69
```

#### The better solution

**However** I do not think this is the correct approach. A better way may be to implement the attribute modification inside the class itself.

```
class particle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 90
        self.y = 70

    def change_all_attributes(self, attr_type, change_by):
        for attr_name, attr_value in self.__dict__.items():
            if isinstance(attr_value, attr_type):
                setattr(self, attr_name, attr_value + change_by)


particles = [particle() for _ in range(2)]

for particle in particles:
    particle.change_all_attributes(int, -1)
    print(particle.x, particle.y)
```

Outputs

```
89 69
89 69
```

What you get:

- More idiomatic code. The change in the attribute is done by the class, not by arbitrary nested loop somewhere in your code (easier to debug).
- A builtin way to control the type of the modified attributes and by how much they change

This can be taken a step further by using properties' getters and setters.